# Do my files get saved if I upgrade to Ubuntu and then revert it?

Tags: upgrade

I currently use Windows 10 but am planning on upgrading my computer to Ubuntu.

I was wondering if my files would be saved if I upgrade to Ubuntu and then revert the upgrade back to Windows 10. Are my files saved in that case?

Comment: An upgrade for sure but only figuratively. In reality Windows and Ubuntu are two different and completely independent OSes, you don't upgrade from one to another. Depending on the hardware you may replace Windows with Ubuntu or install a dual boot. In any case BACKUP first.

Comment: The short answer is "no", but I'm sensing that you're not very familiar with Ubuntu, so you may want to add some more details to your question, such as the location where the files are stored.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in comments you do not "upgrade" from Windows to Ubuntu. You "switch" from Windows to Ubuntu.

During the installation of Ubuntu you are offered a choice between

- *erasing* Windows and all other data from the drive to install Ubuntu in their stead or
- shrinking the partition with the Windows installation to install Ubuntu *alongside* it (this will retain all other previously existing data) or
- repartitioning the drive(s) and assigning partitions yourself if you have different plans and know what you’re doing, or if the installer can’t figure out how to perform any of the other two options.

When operating in Windows most users create documents with Microsoft Office.

When in Ubuntu most users create documents with LibreOffice (called LO for short). LO has the ability to save files in both Ubuntu format (simplistic term) and Microsoft Office format.

Usually you will operate in "dual boot mode" where both Windows and Ubuntu are installed on your machine and whenever you "reboot" your machine you pick which operating system (Windows or Ubuntu) you want to run.

While operating in Ubuntu you can open and save documents within Windows.

Hope this clears the air for you.